# Load Class in application core's sub-folders in Code Igniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, hmvc

In my `application/core` directory, I had class `MY_Controller`.
And now, I want to create two classes in two paths `application/core/Frontent/Frontend_Controller.php` and `application/core/Backend/Backend_Controller.php`. Then my modules controllers extend from Frontend_Controller and Backend_Controller class.
But CI always raises class not found error.

---

**Edit March 20th 2014:**

I used @manix's suggestion:
1. Write below script at the end of `/application/config/config.php`

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/Frontend/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }

        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/Backend/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

1. Create `/application/core/Backend/Backend_Controller.php` like this:

```
(defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Backend_Controller extends CORE_Controller {

}
```

1. I have a Menu class extends Backend_Controller. Then receive this error `Fatal error: Class 'Backend_Controller' not found in codeigniter\application\widgets\menu\Controllers\menu.php on line 6`. If I put the Backend_Controller.php at `/application/core/Backend_Controller.php`, it is OK. But I want to put it into a subfolder.

**SOLUTION (update March 24th 2014)**
Thank to manix. I edited from his code to load classes. Here is the code that works for me.

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/Frontent/' . $class . EXT)) {
            include $file;
        }

        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/Backend/' . $class . EXT)) {
            include $file;
        }

        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT)) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you try applicatiion/core/Fronted_Controller.php?

Comment: Yes, I tried, and it was successful. But I want to put it into subfolder of core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call explicitly the `__autoload` funtionat the end of the config.php file that raised at `application/config/` folder. Look the example above:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/Frontent/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }

        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/Backend/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question. Please see above for more information. Thanks.

Comment: There are some contradictions. 1: You said that you want the Back_End class in `application/core/Backend/` subfolder. Then, you say that `Then receive this error Fatal error: Class 'Backend_Controller' not found in codeigniter\application\widgets\menu\Controllers\menu.php on line 6. If I put the Backend_Controller.php at /application/core/Backend_Controller.php, it is OK`. This tells to me that the code I posted is correct, and you are placing the backend controller in an unknown path

Comment: Because Menu class extends from Backend_Controller class. If I place Backend_Controller in /application/core/ it OK and no need using your code. I want to place it in /application/core/Backend/.

Comment: There is still some class that Backend_Controller and Frontend_Controller are extended from. I had some update from your code. Thanks for your helps, my friend!